# CSS query to select tags

Tags: css

i want a query to select span tags inside label tag after checking that input tag(checkbox) is checked. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have an example html?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript ?

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

This code will only work if you keep the order, meaning the label *after* the checkbox.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label>span {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<label>This is a label <span>with a span</span> that colours yellow</label>
```

## jQuery alternativ

In case you want the label before the input, you'll need some jQuery to do the same trick. Note that the input field needs a name, and you'll need to set the `for` attribute on your label.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    var label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"] span');
    label.toggleClass('yellow', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="field">This is a label <span>with a span</span> that colours yellow</label>
<input name="field" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: While this is a good answer I do believe the OP should have been encouraged to try to put forth some effort.  SoF is supposed to be a support group not a free work group.  Personal opinion.

Comment: This will apply to all subsequent labels when repeating the construct. use `+` rather than `~` if you want only the label directly following the checkbox.

Comment: @MorganGreen, I do agree with you, but when the code is a simple as this, (simple as in not much effort for me), I rather share my knowledge, than point out that his question is low quality... others already pointed that out.

Comment: @connexo, good point! I oversaw that... and edited it! Thank you.